# Google Sheets Array Formula Match on Multiple Conditions, 1 being date that is less than or equal to

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I am hoping someone can help me out.

I have 2 different datasets and I am hoping to replicate something like the maxifs function using an arrayformula so that I only need 1 formula and do not need to drag it down.

What I would like to do is return a value that matches a name, and the date is less than or equal to a date in the column. Basically the most recent value that matches those criteria.

I have added a picture below

[DEMO FIXED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPzQ2.png)

The maxifs formula I am trying to replicate in this case is: `=maxifs(I:I, A:A, G:G, H:H, "<=" & B:B)`

Sample Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mMMT1JbBMTAM0togUFQtctpY5FKzgVaP2_YKnALoHAE/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**:
I have this formula

```
=arrayformula(if(len(A2:A), vlookup(A2:A&B2:B, {H2:H&I2:I, J2:J}, 2, false),))
```

Which almost does what I want, however if there is no date matching i need the value from the next most recent date. Instead this returns an error.

Comment: Your "UPDATE" formula actually isn't close to doing what you want, at least not as I understand the goal. For instance, if the amount on 1/1/201 had been $500, then that would have been the max for all dates given for Person 1. A simple lookup, whether with exact matching or fall-back matching on date will only find the exact or closest previous date's amount, whether the max-to-date or not.

Comment: I am sorry,
I do not think I explained the use case well enough. 

I need to return the value that matches the name, and is from the closest date that is less than or equal to the lookup date. 

It does not need to be a max value.

Comment: Your sheet and "Demo" image do not reflect what you said in the comment above. For 2/1/2021, you show a value of 130, which is the max to that date. If you just wanted the amount on that date or the closest previous, it would have been 110. So you'll want to think carefully about what you want and edit your post, image and sample spreadsheet accordingly.

Comment: Please also remove the "maxifs" tag from your post, as it is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new goal has nothing to do with your post. Your image values don't match your sheet, and you don't want a max or equivalent to MAXIFS at all now. So the entire post will be confusing to other contributors and future site visitors. Consider spending adequate time to rework your post question, image and spreadsheet to accurately reflect your new goal in a unified way.

That said, I've added a new sheet ("Erik Help") with a formula highlighted in green which accomplished your new goal as I understand it:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,VLOOKUP(A2:A&"~"&B2:B,SORT({G2:G&"~"&H2:H,I2:I},1,1),2,TRUE)))`

**ADDENDUM** (based on additional comment from OP):

I've modified the formula as follows:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,IFERROR(IF(REGEXEXTRACT(VLOOKUP(A2:A&"~"&B2:B,SORT(G2:G&"~"&H2:H),1,TRUE),"(.+)~")<>A2:A,"no match",VLOOKUP(A2:A&"~"&B2:B,SORT({G2:G&"~"&H2:H,I2:I},1,1),2,TRUE)))))`

Comment: This formula is really close, however when I add new data it will find matches where there are not any. 

Example if I was to add person 11 to the data it matches for a value for them even though person 11 does not exist in the dataset. Is there a way to make sure that the match on name is exact, and the match on date is less than or equal or next closest?

Cheers.

Comment: See my "ADDENDUM" to the above post (which I've also updated within my originally added sheet in your sample spreadsheet).

Comment: AMAZING!
Thank you!